# Set a random application background image iOS 6

Tags: ios, sdk, background, uiimageview

I would like to set a random background image for my application, so that every time somebody launches the app a new background image is displayed.

Here´s what ive tried so far in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`
 method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSMutableArray *myImageNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.png", @"image2.png", @"image3.png", nil];
   int index = arc4random() % [myImageNames count];
   UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]];
   self.window.backgroundColor = background;
}
```

I get no error but i doesn´t work... 
Any ideas?
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSMutableArray *myImageNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.png", @"image2.png", @"image3.png", nil];
   int index = arc4random() % [myImageNames count];
   UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]]];
   self.window.backgroundColor = background;
   [background release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of delegate class put this code in your main viewcontrller's initWithNibName method:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        NSMutableArray *myImageNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.png", @"image2.png", @"image3.png",@"image4.png", @"image5.png",@"image6.png",   nil];
        int index = arc4random() % [myImageNames count];

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing something in your code while you are setting Background color from the Image

See `[myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]`, this code will return the just string object.

since you are just passing the `string` to the method which required a `image`.

So You should have changed that piece of code to this

`[UIImage imageNamed:[myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]`.

Now You code will look like this

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
   NSMutableArray *myImageNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.png", @"image2.png", @"image3.png", nil];
  int index = arc4random() % [myImageNames count];
  UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:  [myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]]];
  self.window.backgroundColor = background;
  [background release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to consider. First, you need to pass `UIImage`, not `NSString`, to `initWithPatternImage`. The code should be:

```
 NSMutableArray *myImageNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.png", @"image2.png", @"image3.png", nil];
  int index = arc4random() % [myImageNames count];
  UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:  [myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]]];
  self.window.backgroundColor = background;
  [background release];
```

The other thing is that when iOS instantiates the main storyboard, it does a few things for you. One of those things is allocating and initializating the `self.window` property, but it also instantiates the main view controller contained in your storyboard and assigns it to the `UIWindow`'s `rootViewController` property. This means that if your main view controller creates a `UIView` (as almost every view controller does), its background will visually override the `UIWindow` background, unless it's set as transparent. As setting a transparent `UIView` may not be what you want, and it is awkward by the way, I'd recommend setting the background to your root view controller's view, following @Dilip answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got i working thanks to all of you who replied, thank you all!

The code should be:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSMutableArray *myImageNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.jpg", @"image2.jpg", @"image3.png", nil];
    int index = arc4random() % [myImageNames count];
    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = background;
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```